# dereferencing a created pointer

Tags: pointers, reference, dereference

I just have a quick question about what this code mean. Sorry, been reading other posts but I couldn't fully grasp the concept since none seems to resemble this piece of code that I'm currently working in my embedded system.

```
int8u buf[1024];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
*((int16u*)&buf[2]) = 0xbb01;
```

can someone explain to me what these lines mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically interprets the array of bytes `buf` as 16-bit words and then changes the second word to `0xbb01`. Alternative representation:

```
int8u buf[1024];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

int16u *words = buf;
buf[1] = 0xbb01;
```

`&buf[2]` takes the address to the second byte in `buf`. Then the cast to `(int16u *)` informs the compiler that the result is to be treated as a 16-bit unsigned integer. Finally, the memory on that address is set to `0xbb01`.

Depending on the endianness of your system, the contents of `buf` could then be `0x00, 0x00, 0xbb, 0x01` or `0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xbb` (followed by more NULs due to the `memset()`).

Comment: what does the sizeof(buf) do in the memset? memset copies the "0" from the leftmost bit of buf right? e.g. [0 0 0 ... ] 
sorry, but I'm new to "endian", but thank you for the help!

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` returns the size of `buf` in bytes. In this example that would be 1024 times the size of int8u, so `sizeof(buf) == 1024`. That memset line initializes the whole `buf` array to 0s.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comment of the code for explanation

```
int8u buf[1024];                  // intializing int array of size 1024 in RAM. 

memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));      // fill in buffer with zero.
```

`(int16u*)&buf[2]` is a type casting for pointer which points to int16. here casting is given to &buf[2] i.e. address of buf[2].

```
*((int16u*)&buf[2]) = 0xbb01;  //  updating content of int16 -two byte intger starting at buf2
```

***Why this is done ?***

This is done as `buf` array was created is of ***int8u***. and now we need to update int16 value `0xbb01`. To do this, in above code we have created int16 pointer.

***Step by Step simplification of above pointer***

1. *((int16u*)&buf[2]) = 0xbb01;
2. updating content of ((int16u*)&buf[2]) by 0xbb01
3. &buf[2] is pointer to int16u and update its value by 0xbb01
4. update value at buf[2],buf[3] by 0xbb01.[#]

[#]: exact content of buf[2], buf[3] will depend on type of core architecture: big endian or small endian.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in explaining!Thumbs up! I like your answer too but sadly can't vote 2, but thank you for the response good sir!